# How to do a multiple term search within an element

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am attempting to do a search which checks that each word within a query string is contained within a specific element. For example, if the `$query = "Sports With Stripes"` then the specific element must contain all three words (In any order, so it is not a phrase).

To restrict the search to the element I have the following constraint:

```
        <constraint name="inelement">
            <word>
                <element ns="" name="myElement"/>
                <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
            </word>
        </constraint>
```

This seems okay, but I am struggling when it comes to what do put in the `search:search`. I first attempted this:

```
search:search('inelement:spots with stripes', $options, 1, 25)
```

This did not work as it just restricts `"spots"` to my element.

I then tried the following, which does get me the results I need but I was wondering if this is the only way to achieve this or if there is another way such as using an operator in-between my search terms.

```
search:search('inelement:spots inelement:with inelement:stripes', $options, 1, 25)
```

Is there a better way? Or do I manually have to parse my queryString to separate them in to individual words before adding the constraint to my `search:search`?

Answer (score 1):

To apply a constraint across whitespace, use quotes.

```
inelement:"spots with stripes"
```

With the default parser that will return a single element-word term. To break the term into words, you could write a custom parser function. There is an example at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750

You may want a `cts:near-query` to ensure that all three words are in the *same* element. And you may need to enable `element-word-positions` in the database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `search:search` you can use a combination of `search:parse` and `search:resolve` and do your own custom processing in between. If you want to always search within a specific element, you can update the query in between those steps.

```
declare function local:word-to-element-query(
  $element as xs:QName,
  $query as item()
) as item()
{
  typeswitch ($query)
  case element(cts:word-query)
    return cts:element-word-query($element, 
      $query/cts:text/string(),
      $query/cts:option/string())
  case text() return $query
  default return 
    element { node-name($query) } {
      $query/@*, local:word-to-element-query($element, $query/node())
    }
};

let $query := 
  local:word-to-element-query(
    xs:QName('myElement'),
    search:parse('spots with stripes'))
return search:resolve($query)
```

The recursive typeswitch template is a good strategy for modifying the default parse output and adding other custom logic.